# Использование псевдоклассов для тегов select

Tags: css, html5

Как сделать, чтобы при выборе оценки рамка вокруг оценки 2 была в красном цвете, а при выборе оценки 5  - рамка вокруг неё была в зелёном цвете?

```css
#form1 {
  float: left;
}

:in-range {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

:out-of-range {
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <form name="form1" action="request.php" method="post">

    <label>Ф.И.О:</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше Ф.И.О..." name="fio"><br><br>
    <label>Оценка 1:</label>
    <select size="1" min="3" max="5" value="1" name="otvet">
 
 <optgroup label="варианты оцкенок:">
 <option >"1"</option> 
 <option >"2" </option>
 <option >"3"</option> 
 <option>"4"</option>
 <option>"5"</option>    
 </optgroup>
 
</select>
    <br><br>
    <label>Оценка 2:</label>
    <select size="1" min="3" max="5" value="1" name="otvet">
 
 <optgroup label="варианты оцкенок:">
 <option >"1"</option> 
 <option class="two">"2" </option>
 <option >"3"</option> 
 <option>"4"</option>
 <option class="five">"5"</option>    
 </optgroup>
 
</select>

  </form>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут без JavaScript никак не обойтись

```js
$('#answer').change(function(){
  var answer = +this.value;
  switch(answer){
    case 2:
      $(this).css('border-color','red');
      break;
     case 5:
      $(this).css('border-color','green');
      break;
     default:
      $(this).css('border-color','');
  }
})
```

```css
select:focus{
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="answer" id="answer">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Благодарю, вас!